# find points in vector where change is greater than threshold

Tags: r

I want to find positions in a vector where the value differs by more than some threshold value from an earlier point in the vector.  The first change-point should be measured relative to the first value in the vector.  Subsequent change-points should be measured relative to the previous change-point.

I can do this using a `for` loop, but I wonder if there is a more idiomatic and faster vectorised soultion.

**Minimal example:**

```
set.seed(123)
x = cumsum(rnorm(500))

mindiff = 5.0
start = x[1]
changepoints = integer()

for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  if (abs(x[i] - start) > mindiff) {
    changepoints = c(changepoints, i)
    start = x[i]
  }
}

plot(x, type = 'l')
points(changepoints, x[changepoints], col='red')
```

[image]

Comment: The problem for vectorizing your code is that `start` is changing along the way. I think your only remaining solution is to recode this loop in Rcpp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implementing the same code in `Rcpp` can help with speed.

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction(
  "IntegerVector foo(NumericVector vect, double difference){
    int start = 0;
    IntegerVector changepoints;
    for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++){
      if((vect[i] - vect[start]) > difference || (vect[start] - vect[i]) > difference){
        changepoints.push_back (i+1);
        start = i;        
      }
    }
    return(changepoints);
  }"
  )

foo(vect = x, difference = mindiff)
# [1]  17  25  56  98 108 144 288 297 307 312 403 470 487

identical(foo(vect = x, difference = mindiff), changepoints)
#[1] TRUE
```

**Benchmarking**

```
#DATA
set.seed(123)
x = cumsum(rnorm(1e5))
mindiff = 5.0

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(baseR = {start = x[1]
changepoints = integer()

for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    if (abs(x[i] - start) > mindiff) {
        changepoints = c(changepoints, i)
        start = x[i]
    }
}}, Rcpp = foo(vect = x, difference = mindiff))
#Unit: milliseconds
#  expr        min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
# baseR 117.194668 123.07353 125.98741 125.56882 127.78463 139.5318   100   b
#  Rcpp   7.907011  11.93539  14.47328  12.16848  12.38791 263.2796   100  a
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution just using baseR [`Reduce`](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html#functionals-fp). Using the argument `accumulate = TRUE`, reduce returns the result of every call to the function. In our case it will represent `start` value of the solution using the `for` loop. Once you have this vector, we only need to find the indexes where the value changes:

```
#Find the changepoints
r <- Reduce(function(a,e) {
  if (abs(e - a) > mindiff)
    e
  else 
    a
  }, x, accumulate =T)

# Get the indexes using diff
# changepoints <- head(cumsum(c(1,rle(r)$lengths)),-1)
changepoints <- which(!diff(r) == 0) + 1
```

**EDIT**:
I have updated the answer using @Eric Watt's comment.

Comment: Cool answer. An alternative to `rle` is to take the `diff` of r and look where it's not zero. This avoids having the first index returned, and might be an easier to understand alternative. `changepoints <- which(!diff(r) == 0) + 1`

Comment: I like this answer for its neatness factor. I should point out, however, that `Reduce` is not optimised for speed, as it is itself just a wrapper for a `for` loop implemented in `R`. So, not really any performance gain from doing it this way. For speed I'll probably end up using @db answer with `Rcpp` instead.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, using recursion, we can get an answer that uses only R vectorised functions. **However, this will not work on large vectors of results.** E.g. In the OP example we get an "evaluation nested too deeply" error when length(x) == 1e5

```
N = length(x)
f.recurs = function(x, mindiff, i=1) {
  next.i = i + which(abs(x[i:N]-x[i]) > mindiff)[1] - 1L
  if (!is.na(next.i)) c(next.i, f.recurs(x, mindiff, next.i))
  else NULL
}

f.recurs(x, 5.0)
# [1]  17  25  56  98 108 144 288 297 307 312 403 470 487
```